# How can I install a waste disposer if I have a high drain fitting?

Tags: plumbing, garbage-disposal

I want to install a waster disposer under my kitchen sink. My problem is that the drain fitting coming into the kitchen under the sink comes out quite high, and the food disposer will effectively have to drain upwards, before it can drain down.

I can put in a trap, but, I'm not sure the how well the disposer will take being that full of water.

Any ideas on how to plumb it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem.  I'm afraid that having a high drain will cause you a lot of problems. My greatest concern is that the disposer will not drain fully and the standing water and waste will cause bacteria growth and foul odors.  This could be very unhealthy in a kitchen area, not to mention unpleasant. I'd look at a way to lower the drain if possible to assure proper drainage.

Comment: I actually broke out the unit specs and a tape measure, and it looks like I have about an inch spare, just, so I'm lucky here. I'll mark you as the answer, given it's what I would expect the answer to be.